# ASP.NET WebApi Identity Facebook login access denied

Tags: facebook-graph-api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, facebook-login, asp.net-identity-2

I'm building a ASP.NET (4.6) WebApi project and I'm using ASP.NET Identity to authenticate with Facebook, Google and Microsoft to my API. I have managed to authenticate with Google and Microsoft, but not with Facebook.
I'm using Visual Studio 2015

The problem is that I get access denied every time I authenticate. The scenario goes like this:

1. I make an API call to localhost:2975/api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true through my browser.
2. I receive a link to my API for every external provider my API support. In the Facebook case I got localhost:2975/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Facebook&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A2975%2F&state=99...01
3. I go to that link with my browser, and gets redirected to the Facebook login page.
4. I authenticate to Facebook, and a dialog window appears and asks permission for the requested information about me.
5. I accept and gets redirected back to my API with the error "access_denied". localhost:2975/api/Account/ExternalLogin gets called.

I haven't figured out where the problem comes from, whether its some permission setting in my Facebook app, the Facebook user I log in with, or if the problem lies in the ASP.NET Identity template.

Regarding Facebook I have created a test app of my app, as well as pushed it as a live app. I can find the app on my Facebook profile, and I've removed it several times. My Facebook profile has the administrator role of the app. I have created test users, as well as added a friend of mine as developer/tester of the app. The problem remains. I read somewhere that there should be a pending request for the app that I should accept, but I haven't found any.

Regarding the ASP.NET Identity template the error is received very early in the process:

AccountController.cs:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExternalLogin(string provider, string error = null)
{
    if (error != null)
    {
        // This is where the API comes in step 5 above
        return Redirect(Url.Content("~/") + "#error=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(error)); 
    }

    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // This is where the API comes in step 2 above before it redirects me to Facebook login 
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, this); 
    }

    ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);

    // Untouched logic
    // ....
}
```

When I use Google Chromes Network tool I can see that I gets redirected to this link:
facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=XXX&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv2.6%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A2975%252Fsignin-facebook%26state%3D...%26scope%3Demail%252Cpublic_profile%26response_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3D...%26ret%3Dlogin%26logger_id%3D...&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A2975%2Fsignin-facebook%3F**error%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied**%26state%3D...%23_%3D_&display=page&locale=sv_SE&logger_id=...
There is a cancel url with predefined error: "access_denied", error code: 200, reason: "user_denied", so maybe the "access_denied" error I receive isn't very accurate?

Other relevant code I can come up with is in Startup.Auth.cs (I never get to the OnAuthenticated part though):

```
var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AppId = "XXX",
    AppSecret = "XXX",
    Scope = { "email", "public_profile" }
};
facebookOptions.Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
{
    OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
    {
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:facebook:access_token", context.AccessToken, ClaimValueTypes.String, "Facebook"));
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:facebook:email", context.Email, ClaimValueTypes.Email, "Facebook"));
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
};
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

It feels like I've tried everything. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Late update: There was nothing wrong with my code. After I changed some settings in my Facebook app it worked

Comment: Could you please let us know what are the changes you have made in facebook site for which it worked ?

Comment: I am also very curious about these settings...

Answer (score 3):

Update NuGet packages solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503266/webapi-facebook-login-returning-access-denied-when-removing-permissions) post in the line

```
context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:facebook:email", context.Email, ClaimValueTypes.Email, "Facebook"));
```

the context.Email is null.

Comment: this did it for me!

Answer (score 2):

try to update the nuget package which Microsoft.Owin.Security,Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook and so on

Comment: The default template included v3.0.1.  I updated the package to v3.1.0 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Those who were unable to resolve the issue by just updating `nuget` packages, it might help.

Our `Web App` was working fine with External Login, what was happening before was our app redirected the users to `Facebook` or `Google` for authentication and returned the relevant details from their account. But then this issue arises in which the redirect url contains an error with a value `Access_Denied`. which is not descriptive at all so you need to manually find the errors.

After a lot of debugging and `nuget` updates I was still unable to resolve the issue and then it turned out the solution was the IP `whitelisting` for the server as our IT team and few developers changed the the server settings or migrated the website to new server which obviously had a different `IP`. Hence, I added the IP address in Facebook dev console to `whitelist` the address and it worked like a charm.

Whereas, Google authentication was fixed without whitelisting anything, just updating the `nuget` packages did the job.