# Facebook Login using Owin Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm trying to make a facebook login but whatever I do I keep getting an access denied error.

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
            facebookOptions.AppId = "appId";
            facebookOptions.AppSecret = "appSecret";
            facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
        }
    }
```

Facebook Login button

```
protected void FacebookLogin_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "Login.aspx" };
        Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, "Facebook");
    }
```

When I press the button I get redirected to facebook and once I login in facebook I get redericted back to the login page but in de querystring I keep getting the access denied error. I'm pretty sure my login details are correct because when I press the button a second time I don't see the facebook page anymore I am immediatly redirected back to the login page.

Why do I keep getting the access denied error. I have set everything in the facebook also using [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on)

I sure hope anyone can help me on this.

Comment: Check if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503266/webapi-facebook-login-returning-access-denied-when-removing-permissions

Comment: I have seen this and tried it but it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm you have given valid app ID and secret ID right? because in the above mentioned code i am seeing variables.

Comment: yeah. thats hidden on this page but its there in my app.

Comment: I'm wondering, could it be because I don't have an SSL installed on my web?

Comment: Do you have last Owin 3.1.0? Facebook make some changes, so I had the same problem before I updated Owin to latest version. Now I do not have access_denied, but still can't read Identities from GetOwinContext().Authentiacation.User.

Comment: I gues this could also be an issue because I was still using a 2.1 version. I updated to 3.1 like you sugested but the access denied error still occures.